# How can gcc generate assembly which can set up stack frame with ENTER instruction

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

I generate assembly code like this with gcc, Can gcc generate code which has ENTER for stack frame?

```
.file   "temp.c"
.text
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
main:
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
movl    $0, -12(%rbp)
movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
movl    $0, %eax
popq    %rbp
ret
.size   main, .-main
.ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0"
.section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Here 's original code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
  int main(){
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
   a = 0;
   b = 0;
   c = 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you care? Optimized code will not have stack frames at all, with or without `enter`.

Comment: Note that the optimization manual says: _"Use push/pop to manage stack space and address adjustments between function calls/returns instead of enter/leave."_ Couldn't find a combination of gcc options that would produce `enter` for me.

Comment: I want to write a compiler than can generate assembly code.And I follow a manual that said program start entry with ENTER, and i want to see some real code assembly to know how to use ENTER. @Jester

Comment: Can only say again: do not use `enter`. Anyway, the instruction set reference documents it properly, what part is unclear.

Comment: learn the instruction set first, THEN write a compiler backend...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**GCC will never emit `enter`** because it's super-slow compared to its normal frame-pointer setup of 2 or 3 single-uop instructions.

(If it makes a frame pointer at all; `gcc -O1` and higher enables `-fomit-frame-pointer`.  Except when optimizing for size, because `x(%rsp)` addressing modes use an extra byte vs. `x(%rbp)` modes.)

```
# equivalent to  enter $24, $0  (4 bytes)
    push   %rbp               # 1 byte
    mov    %rsp, %rbp         # 3 bytes
    sub    $24, %rsp          # 4 bytes only for a non-zero immediate
```

Specifically, on Skylake `enter` is 12 uops, and one per 8-cycle throughput for `enter a, 0` ([Agner Fog's instruction tables](https://agner.org/optimize/)).  With a non-zero nesting level, it's insanely slow, like `87 cycles + 7 * nesting level`.

On Ryzen, `enter` is 12 uops, with one per 16-cycle throughput.

`leave` is fine, though: it's only 3 uops on Intel CPUs.  (That's still one more than `mov %rbp, %rsp` / `pop %rbp` though.  The 3 uops doesn't include a stack-sync uop; it's 3 even if the stack engine was in sync before `leave`.)

---

The only reason to use `enter` would be optimizing for code-size at the expense of speed.  But even `gcc -Os` doesn't care enough about code-size to have an option for that.

Even `clang -Oz` (which will use `push $1` / `pop %rax` to save 2 bytes vs. `mov $1, %eax`) doesn't use `enter`.  ([Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:1.2899450879999999,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'void+bar()%3B+//+function+call+stops+it+from+using+the+red-zone%0A%0Aint+foo()+%7B%0A++++volatile+int+foo+%3D+0%3B%0A++++bar()%3B%0A++++return+3%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:38.66445676408084,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g91,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.0749542399999998,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Os+-fno-omit-frame-pointer',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:37.18750131545161,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.0749542399999998,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Oz+-fno-omit-frame-pointer',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:61.335543235919175,l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4))

**But `enter 0,0` doesn't even save code-size so it's just pure bad.**

> And I follow a manual that said program start entry with ENTER

That's one (obsolete and not recommended) option.

If you want to write your own compiler that makes slow code, go ahead.